# Return of atoi() - C function

Tags: c, atoi

I have random strings and i want to sort them. I need to find those containing only digits (like xyz..., x,y,z are digits); What function to use?

I have tried `atoi("3=fyth433")`. But that returns `3`. I was expecting it to return `0` for a string that contains characters that cannot be parsed as integers.

Comment: Reading some documentation might help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi

Comment: Is there other function that I could use?

Comment: The relevant part of the above reference: "takes as many characters as possible to form a valid integer number representation and converts them to an integer value."

Comment: @BillN. Use to do what? `atoi` is doing what it is supposed to but it is not clear what you want it to do.

Comment: I have random strings and i want to sort them. I need to find those containing only digits (like xyz..., x,y,z are digits);

Comment: Suggest you update your question and explain what you really want to do. Because your question as currently worded is a classic case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: I wrote above more exactly. Sorry.

Comment: One option is [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol). Read that man page carefully. You can check the `endptr` value returned by `strtol` to determine whether the entire string was parsed (ie, entire string is a valid `long`) or whether any invalid characters were encountered.

Comment: `atoi()` performs no error checking. If the argument is not a number, the result is unspecified as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @kaylum: your idea is interesting, but it would accept strings like `"  12"`, `"-1"` and `"+99"` which do contain non-digit characters.

Comment: @chqrlie True. It may or may not be what OP wants/needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple test:

```
if (*buf && buf[strspn(buf, "0123456789")] == '\0') {
    /* buf only contains decimal digits */
}
```

`strspn()` returns the number of characters at the start of its first argument that match one character from the second string.  The extra test on `*buf` avoids matching the empty string.  *The empty string contains only digits* is true as it does not contain anything at all.

If `buf` was read by `fgets`, you would check for `'\n'` instead of `'\0'`, but as correctly pointed out by chux, there is a corner case if the last line does not end with a linefeed:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...

char line[256];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    size_t ndigits = strspn(line, "0123456789");
    if (ndigits > 0 && (line[ndigits] == '\n' || line[ndigits] == '\0')) {
        /* line only contains decimal digits */
    } else {
        /* line is empty or contains at least one non digit character */
    }
}
```

You can also use the function `isdigit()` from `<ctype.h>`, but care must be taken to not pass `char` values directly as they might be negative, invoking undefined behavior.  Here is an alternative:

```
int string_has_only_digits(const char *str) {
    if (!*str) // empty string
        return 0;
    while (isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
        str++;
    return *str == '\0';
}
```

You cannot use `strtol` for this because it accepts an initial sequence of white space and an optional sign.

Comment: You might want to add a comment why and how this works. Also, would you mind adding my remark about `ctype.h`?

Comment: Corner case: `if (*line != '\n' && line[strspn(line, "0123456789")] == '\n')` fails when the last line has numbers yet no trailing `'\n'`.  Perhaps just trim a  potential `'\n'` and look for `'\0'`?  IAC, `string_has_only_digits()` is direct and best.